# How to change the direction of PrimeFaces' "Wizard" and "PanelGrid" to RTL

Tags: java, primefaces, arabic, bidirectional

I'd like to know if there is anyway to set the direction to RTL on the following PrimeFaces components:

1. PanelGrid.
2. Wizard

[This post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2283) says that primefaces has gone bidirectional: but does that change include the two components in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primefaces has not fully gone bidirectional because its a process that will take alot of time to do, If you want something to go RTL,

First application level conversion:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.DIR</param-name>
   <param-value>RTL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

if that did not help, then you'll have to do it by hand.You'll need to find the classes of the generated components and convert their float and direction in css, all classes are specified in the Primefaces manual http://primefaces.org/documentation.html.

Comment: Thank you.
Problem is fixed.
I fixed the problem for the PanelGrid by adding the "direction: rtl;" css attribute for its parent DIV.
As for the Wizard component's tabs I added the following in my css file:
.ui-wizard-step-title {
 float: right !important;
}

Comment: yes when it comes to primefaces you always need to look for the classes when you need to modify anything, better yet you can look online for people who already made class overrides, one that I suggest that you look into from now is the PickList